# Where is my Syntax Error? javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var userChoice = function(answer) 
{
    prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
}
var computerChoice = Math.random()
console.log(computerChoice)
if (computerChoice is between 0 and 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice is between 0.34 and 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

I get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Where is my error?

Comment: There's no `is between` construct in javascript.

Comment: `if (computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice < 0.33)`

Comment: You need to use inequality operators (<,>) instead of "is between," and logical operators instead of "and" (&&,||)

Comment: Out of curiosity is there any language that has an `is between` operator?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 The nearest I know of is the `BETWEEN` operator in SQL.

Comment: http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as an "in between" operator. You need to use `>=` and `<=` like so:

```
var userChoice = function(answer) 
{
    prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
}
var computerChoice = Math.random()
console.log(computerChoice)
if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use a language please take some time to look up the syntax.

There is no 'is...and' construct.

You must use logical AND like some of the comments have pointed out:

```
if (computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice < 0.33)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to test for the lower bound.

try this:

```
var userChoice = function(answer) {
    prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
};

userChoice();
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice < 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log(computerChoice);
```